# Mismatching strings in Android studio

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

This is a random bug, but consistent when present.

My `strings.xml` has texts like

```
<string name="intro_text_view">Intro</string>
<string name="intro_now_text_view">Now</string>
<string name="intro_tomorrow_text_view">Tomorrow</string>
<string name="intro_yesterday_text_view">Yesterday</string>

<string name="start_chronometer_button">Start</string>
<string name="stop_chronometer_button">Pause</string>
<string name="reset_chronometer_button">Reset</string>
```

after which I create a textview on my UI xml using Design, but the textviews are getting different text from what I've defined.

E.i: If I create a textview with `@string/intro_text_view`, what I would see as the text is Reset

Any idea why this is happening? Is this a known bug? Or am I doing something dumb?

Thanks in advance.

edit: 
I found a way around it, but not a real understanding of why it's happening.

If I edit the string to something else say `intro_text2` save it, and change it back everything works. I think there's some sort of memory location mismatch going on. If someone finds out why it's happening, please answer here.

Comment: You pretty much have to be doing something wrong. Please show us your code.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek there's nothing much else, it's almost this on top of hello world and few action listeners. If I take this off, my app would run. But if I add these textviews, it would keep on crashing.

Comment: Same problem here with Android Studio 0.4.3. String missmatching (only in the UI previewer) when everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your project and build again if you're using Eclipse. Eclipse has problems with generation of all the constants for id's, strings, etc. It is pretty normal that you have to do it from time to time.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio, and  the problem persists even after an dot update. I find it very odd.